# My Application allows one user opeartion one at a time but jmeter is able to process the same request multiple time simultaneously withoutany error

Tags: jmeter

My Application allows only one user to login/perform any operation at a time but jmeter is able to do the same process/request multiple times without throwing any error using same user credential simultaneously. I've used record and play function of Jmeter and it is able to do the same request multiple times without throwing any error. I have used multiple users in my thread group that's why it is doing same request multiple time but this should be shown in red or fail as my application support that one user can be used only once to perform any operation.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Dmitri, has got my point correctly but my question is If  i am not using any Assertion in my execution and it's a plain record and play scripts then the work done by jmeter is valid or not considering my application use. If it's right behavior from jmeter as my end goal is to measure the time taken by that request to perform the operation successfully please help me more about the logic or any article for the same.
Is it mandatory to add the assertion or csv i/p to validate my application use or the current working by jmeter is also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter doesn't perform any checks of the response content, it automatically considers HTTP Response codes below 400 as successful.

If your application displays an error message - JMeter won't automatically check for it, it just measures response time. You can add i.e. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to add a check that response contains what it should contain or vice versa, that it doesn't contain patterns like "Error" or "Exception" or whatever.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) for more information on how you can conditionally set pass or fail criteria in your JMeter test.

Comment: Dmitri, you've got my point correctly but my question is If  i am not using any Assertion in my execution and it's a plain record and play scripts then the work done by jmeter is valid or not considering my application use. If it's right behavior from jmeter as my end goal is to measure the time taken by that request to perform the operation successfully please help me more about the logic or any article for the same.
Is it mandatory to add the assertion or csv i/p to validate my application use or the current working by jmeter is also fine.

Comment: @Dimitri : All the user/threads are getting the same response from the server using the same user credentials. Instead of throwing error it's showing the same response data to all the users. How is this possible i literally believe this is a bug as my system allow one user to login once at a time and the Jmeter is showing 3 same responses using the same user credentials logged in simultaneously.??